# Why do I get a "cannot locate" error from reloc_library?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux

I'm porting a certain application from Linux to Android. When I tried to run the executable in the Android emulator I faced the following error:

```
reloc_library[1285]:   867 cannot locate   '_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc'
```

I could sense it is somehow related to `cout`, but I am not sure. Could someone give a hint how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `c++filt` demangles this to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)`

Comment: @Mankarse, How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: In my experience these sorts of problems are related to incompatible C++ standard library versions, and are sometimes very difficult to solve. Check which version of `libstdc++` you are compiling with, and ensure that it is the same version as that loaded in by the emulator.

Comment: @Mankrse, Thanks for the reply. I am new to android environment, how to find the  libstdc++ version on both the side ?. ie. from emulator, and the library which i m using to compile the code ? But in the include director, i see like : /arm-linux-androideabi/include/c++/4.4.3/iostream

Comment: I am new to android too. I have a few ideas though: Try using `ldd` to list the dependencies of your binary. Also try using the `__GLIBCXX__` macro to find the version that you are compiling with (documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html)).